# No of subsets of a given array such that their product is in the form of p1*p2*p3

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, prime-factoring

Given an array A of size n. You have to find the number of subsets such that their product is in the form of p1×p2×p3… where p1,p2,p3,… are prime numbers. No prime number should appear more than once.

Example: Lets pick an array A of size 5. A[5]={2,3,15,55,21} The subsets in our answers should be {2}, {3}, {15}, {55}, {21}, {2,3},{2,15},{2,55},{2,21},{2,3,55},{2,55,21},{3,55},{55,21}. Lets take {2,3,55} The product will be 2×3×55=2×3×5×11. Thus all prime numbers with power of 1. We can't take for example {3,15} because 3×15=3^2×5. Condition not satisfied. Therefore our answer should be number of subsets i.e. here 13.

Constraints: 2≤A[i]<10^9, 1≤n<10^5

Note: Simple recursion gives Time Limit Exceeded

Comment: `3×15=32×5` - I guess you meant `3x3x5`.

Comment: How are the products of {2} or {2, 3, 55} in the "form of p1×p2×p3… where p1,p2,p3,… are prime numbers?"

Comment: @גלעדברקן   {two, 3, 55} = > 2x3x55 = 2x3x5x11 where 2,3,5,11 are all prime numbers whose power is 1. {2} => 2

Comment: Oh, my bad, I was thinking it should be exactly three primes :)

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful. Idea: factor all elements of the array and remove the ones with duplicate prime factors. Construct a graph with one vertex for each of the remaining numbers. Add an edge between any pair of numbers that share a prime factor. The number of valid subsets should be equal to the number of independent sets in this graph.

Comment: Apparently counting independent sets is #P-complete, so my approach doesn't work for the given constraints